# Proper JSON Escaping in Clojure API

Tags: json, clojure, compojure

I have a Clojure function that writes out the contents of a vector of URLs to JSON, and returns this from an API endpoint. This endpoint data is read by an Elm JSON Decoder on a frontend app. Running this Clojure function directly gives me the following:

```
(json/write-str ["http://www.example.com?param=value" "http://www.example2.com?param=value"])
```

Which returns:

```
"[\"http:\\/\\/www.example.com?param=value\",\"http:\\/\\/www.example2.com?param=value\"]"
```

Wonderful! If I input this result directly into an Elm Decoder such as this:

```
stringArrayDecoder : Json.Decoder.Decoder (List String)
stringArrayDecoder =
Json.Decoder.list Json.Decoder.string
```

It parses it happily with no error.

However, when I view the JSON response from the endpoint, it is losing some of the escaping and I get this:

```
["http:\/\/www.example.com?param=value","http:\/\/www.example2.com?param=value"]
```

Which my Elm decoder cannot read.

How do I avoid this? How can I get the fully escaped JSON values produced by my internal function through the API endpoint and into my Elm frontend Decoder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON allows you to [escape forward slashes](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) `/` and other characters as to prevent stuff like `</` from popping up in html.

[`write-str`](https://clojure.github.io/data.json/#clojure.data.json/write-str) has an `:escape-slash` boolean option:

> :escape-slash boolean
>
> If true (default) the slash / is escaped as \/

Thus you can instead write

```clj
(json/write-str ["http://url.one" "http://url.two"] :escape-slash false)
=> "[\"http://url.one\",\"http://url.two\"]"
```

Comment: Valid workaround - yet i'd like to see this addressed in the elm side if it where my project.

Comment: I tried it out and that Elm decoder works... albeit the error 
> my = Json.Decode.decodeString (Json.Decode.list Json.Decode.string) j
Ok ["http://www.example.com?param=value","http://www.example2.com?param=value"]
    : Result Json.Decode.Error (List String)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Remy. I am able to parse the direct output of that updated write-str command as well, though I'm still seeing the issue I mentioned where it's losing the outside double quotes when returned from the API. I may ask a separate question regarding an Elm decoder that will work for the non-quoted JSON array, or better specifying my issue. However your answer was helpful in its own right so I've marked it as such!

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand the question better. Maybe the confusion is in what `write-str` actually does, which is different from what an API would return. I'd suggest you use [`write`](https://clojure.github.io/data.json/#clojure.data.json/write) instead and build your decoder based on that.